# I want to change the Y axis of a graphic (excel)

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I want to modify to y axis in "image1" so that the values range from 0 to 7 rather than from 0 to 18.

I attach my example (image1) and an original example (image3)

thank you for your help

Image 1
[image: image1]

Image 3
[image: image3]

Comment: Question better suited for SUPERUSER stack site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

click on your graph.  Select the Y axis.  Set you min and max values to what you want instead of automatic.

Comment: thank you a lot Forward, I resolve the problem by choosing the fourth diagram template instead of the fifth diagram